# How can I solve this limit without L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\ln(1+x)}$$ I tried to do it, but I couldn't. Please, help

Comment: Do you know about Taylor series?

Comment: Write it as $\frac{x}{2}\frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{(x/2)^2}\frac{x}{\ln(1+x)}$, by using that $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(x/2)$. Then use that $\sin(x)/x\to1$ and $\ln(1+x)/x\to1$, as $x\to0$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, this is done using "notable limits". For instance,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x} =0 , \quad \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (x+1)}{x} = 1.
$$

So,

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{\ln(x+1)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{\ln(x+1)}\right) = 0 \times 1 = 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

As the user **Clayton** said right we need to use here the Taylor series.

It is very well known, that
$$
\bbox[lightgreen]
{
\cos(x)=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{24}-....\right)
},
\\
\bbox[lightblue]
{
\ln(1+x)=\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....\right)
},
\implies
\\
\implies{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\ln(1+x)}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^4}{24}+....\right)}{\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....\right)}=
\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\left(\frac{x}{4}-\frac{x^3}{24}+....\right)}{x\left(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-....\right)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{0}{1}=0,
\implies
\\
\implies
\bbox[pink]
{
{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\ln(1+x)}}=0
}.
$$

Comment: +1 for the answer but I think that the exclusion of L'Hôpital's rule (almost direct consequence of Taylor's approximation) should also exclude this approach.

Comment: I would probably drop the dots and use the remainder formula.